# Prevent arrow keys from changing selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a couple of radio buttons and I would like to prevent the pressing of the up/down arrow keys to change the selected radio button.

If you select one of the radio buttons and then press the up/down arrow key it will select the previous or next radio button. Instead I want the selection to remain unchanged. For this I could just use `event.preventDefault();` on certain key presses. However I still want the user to be able to scroll up and down on the page by pressing the arrow keys.

How do I do that?

Radio buttons:

```
<label>Value
    <input type="radio" name="myradiobtn" value="value1">
</label>
<label>Value
    <input type="radio" name="myradiobtn" value="value2">
</label>
<label>Value
    <input type="radio" name="myradiobtn" value="value3">
</label>
<label>Value
    <input type="radio" name="myradiobtn" value="value4">
</label>
<label>Value
    <input type="radio" name="myradiobtn" value="value5">  
</label>
```

Javascript attempt (not working):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var arrowKeys = [37,38,39,40];
    if (arrowKeys.indexOf(e.which) !== -1) {
        $('input[type="radio"]').each(function( index ) {
          $(this).blur();
        });
    }
});
```

JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w0jh9ney/

Comment: Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0jh9ney/3/).

Comment: This kind of works but in order to use the arrow keys for scrolling you first have to manually deselect the  radio buttons which is a little awkward to do especially for regular users

Comment: You're right - I forgot about `.blur()`. [Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0jh9ney/5/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. One minor issue: the first up/down key press doesn't scroll (but this can be simulated by using `$(window).scrollTop()`) only subsequent ones make the page scroll but apart from this that's exactly what I had in mind. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: I have tried some ideas to fix this issue, but was not successful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea is to remove focus from `input` and to prevent default behaviour in `input` `keydown` event handler:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0jh9ney/5/).

```
$('input[type="radio"]').keydown(function(e)
{
    var arrowKeys = [37, 38, 39, 40];
    if (arrowKeys.indexOf(e.which) !== -1)
    {
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Mentioned by @user3346601 workaround for not scrolling on first `keydown`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0jh9ney/6/).

```
$('input[type="radio"]').keydown(function(e)
{
    var arrowKeys = [37, 38, 39, 40];
    if (arrowKeys.indexOf(e.which) !== -1)
    {
        $(this).blur();
        if (e.which == 38)
        {
            var y = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(window).scrollTop(y - 10);
        }
        else if (e.which == 40)
        {
            var y = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(window).scrollTop(y + 10);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution has one issue: the first up/down key press does not scroll the page up or down and only subsequent up/down presses make the page scroll. To solve this add the following after `$(this).blur();`. Add: `if (e.which == 38) { 
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    $(window).scrollTop(y-10);
}
if (e.which == 40) { 
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    $(window).scrollTop(y+10);
}`

Comment: @user3346601 well, yes, it will work, but I tried to be accurate and to trigger `keydown` or `keyup` event for `<body>`, but it somewhy doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var disableArrowKeys = function(e){
    if($("input[type=radio]").is(':focus')){
        if(e.keyCode==37){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.scrollBy(-100, 0);
        }
        else if(e.keyCode==38){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.scrollBy(0, -100);
        }
        else if(e.keyCode==39){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.scrollBy(100, 0);
        }
        else if(e.keyCode==40){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.scrollBy(0, 100);
        }
    }
}
$(document).keydown(disableArrowKeys);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please include an explanation along with your code to fully answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I think I got a simple solution after reading all the comments here that would benefit future visitors.
As Regent said, "*The idea is to remove focus from input*".
So just blur the focus after a click.

```
$('input:radio[name="myradiobtn"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).blur();
})
```