# stop radio buttons from staying selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I click on my radio buttons then hit an arrow key, it changes the option. Is there a way I can disable this feature and use arrow keys normally for my game (snake)? So after it clicks, no highlighting or selection?

```
  <input type='radio' name='difficulty' onclick='setdiff("easy")'>easy
  <input type='radio' name='difficulty' onclick='setdiff("med")' checked>medium
  <input type='radio' name='difficulty' onclick='setdiff("hard")'>hard
```

I tried `document.getElementById("sketch").focus();` inside of `setdiff`.

Comment: Use javascript to lose focus on the radio buttons after a selection has been made.

Comment: input does not have a closing `</input>`

Comment: Just pass focus to some other element. You may do it at the end of setdiff function.   document.getElementById("mygamediv").focus();

Comment: @Nosyara that didn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent arrow keys from changing selected radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972870/prevent-arrow-keys-from-changing-selected-radio-button)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the focus on your snake is the way to go. You said that setting the focus on `sketch` didn't work and that is probably because `sketch` is not focusable. So make sure you set the focus on an object that can receive focus.

Alternatively, you can remove focus from the radio buttons using the `blur()` function.